# FLYWAY: How to maintain different sets of reference data for different environments

Tags: flyway

We are reviewing flyway as a replacement for Liquibase. However we have an existing database with a huge amount of reference data. As a result we would not always want to import the full set of reference data for all environments (for example development) - is there a standard way of using specific reference data for specific environment targets? Or is there an easy way of importing reference data outside of meta data using flyway?

thanks in advance

Comment: thanks @Axel - will try this out, marked as answered for now - assume it will work. Cheers and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple locations, configured differently per environment as described here: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#db-specific-sql